# Visual Studio continually indexing php files which prevents searching project

Tags: visual-studio

I have a php project. If I attempt to search the entire project using Quick Find [Ctrl+F], Search [Ctrl+Q], or Find in Files [Ctrl+Shift+F], no results are found.

The Find panel displays "Total files searched: 0 (Indexing files... showing partial results.)" The little speech-like bubble on the left side of the status bar is continually animating and also displays, "(Indexing files... Showing partial results.)". It has been doing this (i.e., indexing) for many hours if not days.

I am running Visual Studio 17.5.1.

Ideas?

Comment: Just adding, this is a Visual Studio feature to optimize searches ... maybe it's not expecting so many files in the project.

It's doing the same for me even if I just open a folder (File / Open / Folder) without any VS extension installed.

Comment: FWIW, this is only happening on php projects. I noticed a similar post (https://community.devsense.com/d/838-search-does-not-work-any-more/9) on the DevSense website (the company that enables php debugging using Visual Studio). My php project has about 100 php files. The searching in my C++ projects works fine and they have many more source files.